# Redshift - need query to list user permissions on procedures

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm able to find the owner of procedures. But I'm searching for a Redshift query, which list down the user permissions (execute) on the procedures/functions of a Redshift schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT p.proname sp_name , n.nspname sp_schema , p.proargnames sp_args, p.proowner , pu.usename   FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc p ON p.pronamespace = n.oid 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_user pu on p.proowner = pu.usesysid 
WHERE p.proowner > 1
```